# GraphQL gql Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

Tags: syntax-error, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-tag

I'm attempting to set up Apollo GraphQL support in a new React project, but when I try to compile a query using `gql` I keep receiving the error:

> Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

This is generated by the following code:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const query = gql`
    {
      user(id: 5) {
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }
  `

console.log(query)
```

I'm basing this code off the example code found here: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag

What is the `Name` referred to in the error message? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It should work. Do you use graphql-tag version 2.6.x?

Comment: @Win Yes, I am using graphql-tag version 2.6.1

Comment: Is this relevant? https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/180

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the root of my problem was, but moving all the query code into a separate es6 module fixed the issue. There must have been some kind of contamination from the surrounding code. For reference my query was embedded within a React component.

This works:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const query = gql`
{
  user(id: 5) {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
`

export default query
```

Answer (score 65):

This error occurs mostly when there are unclosed curly braces or when some fields are not properly defined while calling the query.

Answer (score 37):

The accepted answer didn't solve my issue. Instead, it worked if you remove the initial curly brackets.

The query should look like this instead:

```
const query=gql`
  user(id: 5) {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
`
```

Comment: Thanks this was my issue as well. Was doing a mutation and could not figure out that it didn't need the exterior curlies.

Answer (score 19):

The causes could be:

- you are adding a "()" at the beginning for no reason
- you need to add more 'nested' parameters.

Especially if you are using an online GraphiQL editor. Examples:

1- Wrong code (extra parenthesis)

```
{
  allFilms() {
    films {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

2- Wrong code (more parameters need it eg: title)

```
{
  allFilms {
    films {         
    }
  }
}
```

3- Correct code

```
{
  allFilms {
    films {
     title         
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

#### GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "$".

One more example of a similar error (For other users).

`theErrorIsHere` (Could be extra `(` or  `{` before the `$varName`) added before `$speakerId`

**Error code:**

```
const FEATURED_SPEAKER = gql`
  mutation markFeatured($speakerId: ID!, $featured: Boolean!){
    markFeatured(speaker_id: theErrorIsHere$speakerId , featured: $featured){
      id
      featured
    }
  }
`;
```

[image: Error output]

**Correct code:**

```
const FEATURED_SPEAKER = gql`
  mutation markFeatured($speakerId: ID!, $featured: Boolean!){
    markFeatured(speaker_id: $speakerId , featured: $featured){
      id
      featured
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: I had the "Expected Name, found $" too. What I had done wrong was something like:
markfeatured($speaker_id: $speaker_id ...
So you can see I did a sloppy copy and paste meaning to get rid or the extra $ but I did not.

Answer (score 6):

Another cause for this error: you are referencing a type that is defined further down.  Move the type you are referencing up.

For example:

```
    type Launch {
        rocket: Rocket
    }

    type Rocket {
        name: String
    }
```

will throw an error, as `Launch` references `Rocket` before `Rocket` is defined.

The corrected code:

```
    type Rocket {
        name: String
    }

    type Launch {
        rocket: Rocket
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In NestJS framework, this error happened to me because I defiled GraphQL field in my schema.graphql file as:

```
  lastUpdated(): Date
```

Instead it should be just

```
  lastUpdated: Date
```

(it doesn't take any argument)

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'm not using NestJS but your suggestion works for me too.

Comment: It worked for my expressJs code as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got the error because of the following:

```
const GET_POSTS_OF_AUTHOR = gql`
  query GetPostsOfAuthor($authorId: Int!) {
    postsOf($authorId: Int!) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

When it should have been:

```
const GET_POSTS_OF_AUTHOR = gql`
  query GetPostsOfAuthor($authorId: Int!) {
    postsOf(authorId: $authorId) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

erroneously thought $authorId passed through identically to the function call instead of setting a property inside the function call.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got the error simply because I'm adding `:` which I shouldn't have done.

e.g:

```js
const query = `
   query($id: String!) {
      getUser(id: $id) {
        user: {
          id
          name
          email
          createdAt
        }
      }
   }
`
```

If you pay close attention to line 4 of the code above you'll realize that I added `:` after the user before the curly brace, then I began to list the user's data I wanna query and THAT WAS EXACTLY WHERE THE ERROR WAS!
Removing the `:` solve the issue!

It should be:

```js
user {
   id
   name
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you use gql from @clinet/apollo and in the backticks you try to inject dynamic js value. Remove it and replace with normal scalar and it will fix your issue.
example:

`${SOME_MAX_VALUE} -> 20`

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving a similar error server side:

`GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found ]`

I realized the cause in my case was a type definition with an empty array.

This breaks:

```
  type Settings {
    requires: []
  }
```

But this works:

```
  type Settings {
    requires: [String]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the cause was a string value with double-quotes inside double-quotes, like so: `"this "is" bad"`.

Answer (score 0):

On ny side the error was caused by extra {} Curly braces. Solved by just removing them.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. In my case putting the id inside double quote solved the issue as the type of id required string value.

```js
{
        product(id: "${id}") {
            name
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting here in case anyone else had this problem but you also get this error if you accidentally make your query look like json with colons (`:`).

ex:

```
data {
  property {
    key: {
      deepKey
    }
  }
}
```

will give the same error from GQL compile

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue i just resolved it by **delete yarn.lock or package-lock.json** and then **re-installing node_modules**
I was using apollo graphql/client it is used for accessing apollo GQL apis.
Worked for me not sure about you.

Just give it a try.