# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected "$", found Name "input"

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const GET_USERS = gql`
query getAllUsers(input: {$skip: Int, $limit:Int}){
    message
    data: {
     first_name
     last_name
     mobile_number
     email
    }
}`
export default GET_USERS ;
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331103/graphql-gql-syntax-error-expected-name-found)

Comment: Did you read the error? Read the GraphQL query variables section - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables you need to define the type of input and name it with `$input`.